# babel-jest doesn't correctly run on jest

Tags: jestjs, babeljs, babel-jest

I have a folder of code that functions as a plugin, so it is a subdirectory of a main directory. The main directory correctly runs the tests that use import statements, but the subfolder does not. The subfolder has its own .babelrc they are posted below.

.babelrc

```
    {
      "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env"
      ],
      "plugins": [
        ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { "legacy": true }],
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
        "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
        [
          "module-resolver",
          {
            "alias": {
              "example-lib": "./src"
            }
          }
        ]
      ],
      "env": {
        "test": {
          "presets": [
            [
              "@babel/preset-env",
              {
                "modules": "commonjs"
              }
            ]
          ]
        }
      }
    }
```

package.json

```
      "jest": {
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    }
  }

    "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.2.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.3.4",
    "example-lib": "^0.11.4",
    "babel-jest": "^24.5.0"
  },
```

jest --debug

```
{
  "configs": [
    {
      "automock": false,
      "browser": false,
      "cache": true,
      "cacheDirectory": "/private/var/folders/y6/prqm_t9s177bp3zhfyc1czbr0000gn/T/jest_dx",
      "clearMocks": false,
      "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": [
        "/node_modules/"
      ],
      "cwd": "/Users/user/development/repo/lib/plugin",
      "dependencyExtractor": null,
      "detectLeaks": false,
      "detectOpenHandles": false,
      "errorOnDeprecated": false,
      "filter": null,
      "forceCoverageMatch": [],
      "globalSetup": null,
      "globalTeardown": null,
      "globals": {},
      "haste": {
        "computeSha1": false,
        "providesModuleNodeModules": []
      },
      "moduleDirectories": [
        "node_modules"
      ],
      "moduleFileExtensions": [
        "js",
        "json",
        "jsx",
        "ts",
        "tsx",
        "node"
      ],
      "moduleNameMapper": {},
      "modulePathIgnorePatterns": [],
      "name": "d855449ce7629afe8ca2c6248201816b",
      "prettierPath": "prettier",
      "resetMocks": false,
      "resetModules": false,
      "resolver": null,
      "restoreMocks": false,
      "rootDir": "/Users/user/development/repo/lib/plugin",
      "roots": [
        "/Users/user/development/repo/lib/plugin"
      ],
      "runner": "jest-runner",
      "setupFiles": [],
      "setupFilesAfterEnv": [],
      "skipFilter": false,
      "snapshotSerializers": [],
      "testEnvironment": "/Users/user/development/repo/lib/node_modules/jest-environment-jsdom/build/index.js",
      "testEnvironmentOptions": {},
      "testLocationInResults": false,
      "testMatch": [
        "**/__tests__/**/*.[jt]s?(x)",
        "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[tj]s?(x)"
      ],
      "testPathIgnorePatterns": [
        "/node_modules/"
      ],
      "testRegex": [],
      "testRunner": "/Users/user/development/repo/lib/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/index.js",
      "testURL": "http://localhost",
      "timers": "real",
      "transform": [
        [
          "^.+\\.jsx?$",
          "/Users/user/development/repo/lib/node_modules/jest-config/node_modules/babel-jest/build/index.js"
        ]
      ],
      "transformIgnorePatterns": [
        "/node_modules/"
      ],
      "watchPathIgnorePatterns": []
    }
  ],
  "globalConfig": {
    "bail": 0,
    "changedFilesWithAncestor": false,
    "collectCoverage": false,
    "collectCoverageFrom": null,
    "coverageDirectory": "/Users/user/development/repo/lib/plugin/coverage",
    "coverageReporters": [
      "json",
      "text",
      "lcov",
      "clover"
    ],
    "coverageThreshold": null,
    "detectLeaks": false,
    "detectOpenHandles": false,
    "errorOnDeprecated": false,
    "expand": false,
    "filter": null,
    "globalSetup": null,
    "globalTeardown": null,
    "listTests": false,
    "maxConcurrency": 5,
    "maxWorkers": 7,
    "noStackTrace": false,
    "nonFlagArgs": [],
    "notify": false,
    "notifyMode": "failure-change",
    "passWithNoTests": false,
    "projects": null,
    "rootDir": "/Users/user/development/repo/lib/plugin/",
    "runTestsByPath": false,
    "skipFilter": false,
    "testFailureExitCode": 1,
    "testPathPattern": "",
    "testResultsProcessor": null,
    "updateSnapshot": "new",
    "useStderr": false,
    "verbose": null,
    "watch": false,
    "watchman": true
  },
  "version": "24.1.0"
}
```

The error itself:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

Jest encountered an unexpected token

This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.

By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".

Here's what you can do:
 • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
 • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
 • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration.html

Details:

/Users/user/development/repo/lib/plugin/test/SystemDataService.spec.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { example } from './helpers';
                                                                                                ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {

  at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (../../node_modules/jest-runtime/build/ScriptTransformer.js:440:17)
```